# Subseting Dataframe by threshold of a column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe containing information about local elections for municipalities and I would like to keep in my dataset only information related to the two best-voted candidates by municipality.

My dataframe was created using information like this:

```
Candidates <- c('Liza S.', 'John R.', 'Peter F.', 'Ignacio R.', 'Hanna F.', 'Anthony E.', 'Andrew W.')`
Municipality <- ('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
Votes <- c(100, 120, 140, 110, 335, 225, 400)
data <- data.frame(Candidates, Municipality, Votes)
```

And look like this:

```
Candidates     Municipality     Votes
Liza S.              A           100
John R.              A           120
Peter F.             A           140
Ignacio R.           B           110
Hanna F.             B           335
Anthony E.           B           225
Andrew W.            B           400
```

I want that my dataframe look like this:

```
Candidates     Municipality     Votes
    John R.              A           120
    Peter F              A           140
    Hanna F.             B           335
    Andrew W.            B           400
```

Any idea of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dplyr` package for this:

```
library(dplyr)

    data %>% 
       group_by(Municipality) %>% 
       top_n(n = 2, wt = Votes)


# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Municipality [2]
  Candidates Municipality Votes
  <fct>      <fct>        <dbl>
1 John R.    A              120
2 Peter F.   A              140
3 Hanna F.   B              335
4 Andrew W.  B              400
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just subset with `ave()` by Municipality-specific (`rev`ersed) `order()`.

```
dat[ave(dat$Votes, dat$Municipality, FUN=function(x) rev(order(x))) <= 2, ]
#   Candidates Municipality Votes
# 2    John R.            A   120
# 3   Peter F.            A   140
# 5   Hanna F.            B   335
# 7  Andrew W.            B   400
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Candidates = structure(c(6L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("Andrew W.", "Anthony E.", "Hanna F.", "Ignacio R.", 
"John R.", "Liza S.", "Peter F."), class = "factor"), Municipality = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    Votes = c(100, 120, 140, 110, 335, 225, 400)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```r
do.call("rbind",
        lapply(split.data.frame(data, Municipality), 
               function(x) x[rev(order(x$Votes))[1:2],]))    
#    Candidates  Municipality Votes
# A.3   Peter F.            A   140
# A.2    John R.            A   120
# B.7  Andrew W.            B   400
# B.5   Hanna F.            B   335
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using dplyr package;

```
library(dplyr)

# Creating data
Candidates <- c('Liza S.', 'John R.', 'Peter F.', 'Ignacio R.', 'Hanna F.', 'Anthony E.', 'Andrew W.')
Municipality <- c('A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B')
Votes <- c(100, 120, 140, 110, 335, 225, 400)
data <- data.frame(Candidates, Municipality, Votes)

data %>%
  # Grouping by Municipality
  group_by(Municipality) %>%
  # Sorting the data desc by Votes
  arrange(desc(Votes)) %>%
  # Getting first and second highest values for each group
  slice(1:2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

#   # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   # Groups:   Municipality [2]
#   Candidates Municipality Votes
# <fct>      <fct>        <dbl>
# Peter F.   A              140
# John R.    A              120
# Andrew W.  B              400
# Hanna F.   B              335
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much for the clear explanation.